# What is the adjectival form of "primate"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, adjectives

To say a man is close to a primate, what should I use, "primatic" or "primative"?

Comment: [_Primatial_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/primatial) is the word you're looking for, I believe, or else I'm a monkey's uncle.

Comment: Does this adjective mean belonging to the primates or primate-like?

Comment: Usually for adjectives like this, it can mean either.

Comment: @J.R. Well howdy there, Uncle Monkey; how ya doin’?  See my answer for why the OED says that *primatial* is more properly *primatal* when referring to monkeys not cardinals.

Comment: Man is not ***close*** to a primate; man ***is*** a primate.

Comment: So, what did he do to you?

Comment: Please show what research you have done in trying to find an answer to your questions.

Comment: I have to point out that MAN is not LIKE a primate, he IS a primate. On the other hand, a man may be LIKE a LOWER PRIMATE, so that's probably the connotation you're looking for, so you might refer to dragging knuckles or other animalisitc behaviour to make your point.

Comment: I think you should accept the answer by @Mitch, "Simian" As soon as I read it, I thought "That's it!" That's the perfect word for this sense.

Answer (score 6):

***Primate* as an adjective** is a “rare and obsolete” word meaning, per the OED:

> **† B.** *adj*. First, earliest. *Obs. rare.*
>
> - 1554-9 *Songs & Ball*. (1860) 5 ― The gates infernall, Wheryn ower primat parent had closyd us.
> - 1580 Hollyband Treas. Fr. Tong, ― Premier, first or primate.

You don’t want *primate* as an adjective, I’m sure you’ll agree.

However, you may use the **noun *primate* attributively**, in which case it has the normal sense:

> **4**. *Zool.* (Usually with pronunciation `/ˈpraɪmeɪt/`.) A mammal belonging to the order Primates, which includes man, apes, monkeys, and several groups of prosimians. Also *attrib.*

And here are two of the attributive citations:

> - 1967 J. R. & P. H. *Napier Handbk. Living Primates* p. v, ― Animal behaviour, ecology and genetic biology··today dominate basic research trends in primate biology.
> - 1977 Rainier III & Bourne *Primate Conservation* p. xviii, ― All authors of this book agreed that the royalties earned should be used to further primate conservation.

In “primate biology” and “primate conservation”, the word *primate* is not an adjective, **because you do not need one**; it is a noun used attributively in a *noun–noun* compound.  That does not make it an adjective, but that’s perfectly fine.

The catarrhine apes do not include all primates; it excludes the lemurs and such.

The adjectival form for *primate* in that sense is *primatal*, per the OED.  About *primatial* it says that it has two sense, the first being related to the princes of the church, and the second being:

> - **2**. *Zool*. Of or pertaining to the mammalian order Primates: more properly ***primatal***.

Perhaps you would like to use the adjective *primatal*:

> priˈmatal, *a. (sb.) Zool. rare.*
>
> Of or pertaining to the order Primates. Also as *sb*., An animal of this order.
>
> - 1870 Cobbold in *Athenæum* 8 Oct. 468/2 ― It was··held that either of these groups, as we now know them, might have been separately evolved from more generalized primatal types··. The assumedly missing tertiary primatals constituted a great and natural bar to the popular acceptance of the theory of descent by natural selection.

It is, however rare.  I would use the attributive noun instead.

Comment: Can you say "This man is primatial"? Or "she likes primatial men"?

Comment: @Anixx If she likes primatial men, she is a weirdo who goes for celibates in red frocks.  *Primatial* is “more properly *primatal”*.  The other sense is about the Catholic Church.  But just use *primate* as an attributive noun. I don’t think that *male primates* and *primate men* are necessarily the same thing.

Comment: @Anixx No, you can't say the 'primatial man' at least not at all to refer to a man that has the characteristics of an ape. 'Primatial' is entirely used (and is not uncommon) in the Catholic church. But 'the primatial man' for some one who is like a (Catholic position of) primate would sound strange. You'd say 'That man is like a (Catholic) primate'.

Comment: Tchrist, thank you for your as usual great scholarship, but I just want to help emphasize something for the OP. Whatever you call it, an adjective or an attributive noun, what you want to say is 'The man is ape-like' or 'the man is 'simian'. 'The man is _a_ primate' (it has to be noun here, it can't act like an adjective (that is not using the article).

Comment: I just stumbled across a contemporary use of "primate" as an adjective which is new to me. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primate_city): _"A **primate city** is the largest city in its country, province, state, or region, disproportionately larger than any others in the urban hierarchy"_.

Comment: @skomisa Quick, tell the OED! :)

Comment: @Mitch What about "she likes primatal men"?

Comment: @Anixx I'd question her judgement in men.

Comment: @Anixx As to the word 'primatal' I'd find it as weird sounding as 'primatial'. Also rare. Which means that you probably want to use more than one word to get across the concept

Answer (score 2):

You really do not want to use either 'primatic' or 'primative' (as they are not recognized suffixed extensions of 'primate'). Also, 'primatial' mean something else (something specific to the Catholic church). And 'primatal' is just not used at all. 'Primitive' is a very good English word but means 'basic' and has nothing to do with apes.

Interestingly, the formal adjective form of the noun 'primate' is:

> [**primate**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/primate)

as in 'Primate mating behavior is much more varied than that of other mammals.'. But you cannot say 'That man is primate'.

The analogous literary to feline, canine, porcine is

> [**simian**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/simian)

as in 'The detective had simian features, a large brow, hair down his back...' or 'That man is simian.' .

Informally, there really is no appropriate cognate word, and the best way to say it would be

> **ape-like**

as in 'The ape-like man crushed the bottle with his bare hands.' or 'That man is ape-like.' .

Comment: Could be, but doesn't that link *not* show primate as an adjective?  It appears to say the adjectival form is *primatial*.

Comment: Strange, other references say "primatial", not primate as you say. -1

Comment: Looks like _primate_ or _primatial_ can [both](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/primate) work as adjectives. I'm not sure why anyone would downvote this.

Comment: They definitely have different meaning. I cannot say "it is a primate man", but I can say "it is primate milk".

Comment: I also can say "it is a primate individual" which means exactly that the individual belongs to apes or monkeys. It does not mean that it could be a human, just primate-like.

Comment: No Mitch.  The adjective *primate* means something else.  It’s an attributive noun that you’re thinking of. The adjectival form is actually the rare *primatal*, which nobody uses.

Comment: @Anixx: I double-checked what you said, and found [this possible exception](http://books.google.com/books?id=Jr-m3bMy7IUC&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=%22primate+man%22&source=bl&ots=tocOkkpWEg&sig=7hSCPHq4TadKn0y-2UXMFb6j-W4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rDMXUMnnPMHgqgHMyIGwCg&ved=0CGMQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22primate%20man%22&f=false). However, when I located the [actual paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/83/6/1921.full.pdf), that first reference appears to be a _typo_ in the bibliography (it should read _primate brain_, not _primate man_, which would back you up). Just thought you might find that quirk interesting.

Comment: @J.R. In *primate brain*, the word *primate* is an attributive noun, not an adjective.  Not all noun modifiers are adjectives.

Comment: @tchrist: I was referring to Anixx's comment, (primate man vice primate milk), and agreeing with both of you.  As for cardinal vs primate, Collins says _primatial_ can be used for either, though I won't insist it's a better word than _primatal_. It's all part of what "evolved" into a very interesting discussion. :^)

Comment: @tchrist: OK, it's an attributive noun (which acts like in many contexts an adjective). Whatever you call it, you're right, you can't say 'the man is primate' (ugh). But you can say 'the primate house' (the house of primates). But the OP is not clear as to the exact sentence usage that is wanted.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: yes 'primatial' is a perfectly good word in English but not having anything to do with apes. It is the adjective form referring to a 'primate' (a 'first, important person') in the Catholic Church. It is not particularly well-known in English outside that context (a great GRE word though).

Comment: @Mitch: *Primatial* is not just RC. Any Episcopal Church (eg the Episcopal Church of USA, the Church of England, the Church of Nigeria) has primates. The Archbishop of Canterbury is a primate, as is Catherine Jefferts Schori. They are also metropolitans having metropolitical authority, just to throw in a couple more esoteric words!

Answer (score 0):

If none of the previous suggestions work for you, consider the adjective *[catarrhine](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catarrhine)*, "Describing the Catarrhini parvorder of primates (including humans) that have nostrils that are close together and directed frontward or downward".  By the way, to "say a man is close to a primate" is to make a statement about one person.  To speak of everyone, say something like "Humans are [primates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primate)."

Comment: Pity the poor, excluded lemurs.